# JavaScript show and hide multiple content blocks onClick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a menu list and when you click on one of the items it should show the content block relevant to that item using vanilla JavaScript **(No jQuery)**

When it opens the content block for that specific item the other content blocks should be hidden.

**HTML Menu Items:**

```
<div class="our-clients__categories">
  <a href="#0" class="our-clients__categories--category" data-category="technology"><h4>Technology</h4></a>
  <a href="#0" class="our-clients__categories--category" data-category="retail"><h4>Retail</h4></a>
  <a href="#0" class="our-clients__categories--category" data-category="finance"><h4>Finance</h4></a>
</div>
```

**Content Blocks**

```
<div class="company-brands" data-brand="technology">
 <h1>Technology</h1>
</div>
<div class="company-brands" data-brand="retail">
  <h1>retail</h1>
</div>
<div class="company-brands" data-brand="finance">
  <h1>finance</h1>
</div>
```

So e.g. when you click on Technology it must show the content block for Technology and so on.

Any help to get started would be great! Thank you

Comment: This may help : https://codepen.io/rgaspary/pen/YwrOXp

Comment: This is an example of showing and hiding a single element @ivar

Answer (score 2):

```js
const toogleLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.js--company-toggle');
const toogleBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.js--company-item');

// Loop through all links
Array.from(toogleLinks).forEach(link => {
  // add click event
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     // Hide all blocks
     Array.from(toogleBlocks).forEach(item => item.classList.add('js--company-item--hidden'));
        // Get target block
        const target = this.getAttribute('href');
        // Show target block
        document.querySelector(target).classList.remove('js--company-item--hidden');
    }, false);
});
```

```css
.js--company-item--hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="our-clients__categories">
  <a href="#technology" class="our-clients__categories--category js--company-toggle"><h4>Technology</h4></a>
  <a href="#retail" class="our-clients__categories--category js--company-toggle"><h4>Retail</h4></a>
  <a href="#finance" class="our-clients__categories--category js--company-toggle"><h4>Finance</h4></a>
</div>

<div class="company-brands js--company-item" id="technology">
 <h1>Technology</h1>
</div>
<div class="company-brands js--company-item js--company-item--hidden" id="retail">
  <h1>retail</h1>
</div>
<div class="company-brands js--company-item js--company-item--hidden" id="finance">
  <h1>finance</h1>
</div>
```

Or the same with data-attribute

```js
const toogleLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle]');

// Loop through all links
Array.from(toogleLinks).forEach(link => {
        // get tooble elements
        const elementsSelector = link.getAttribute('data-toggle')
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll(elementsSelector);
 // add click event
        link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // Hide all blocks
        Array.from(elements).forEach(item => item.setAttribute('hidden', true));
        // Get target block
        const target = this.getAttribute('href');
        // Show target block
        document.querySelector(target).removeAttribute('hidden')
    }, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="our-clients__categories">
  <a href="#technology" class="our-clients__categories--category" data-toggle=".company-brands"><h4>Technology</h4></a>
  <a href="#retail" class="our-clients__categories--category" data-toggle=".company-brands"><h4>Retail</h4></a>
  <a href="#finance" class="our-clients__categories--category" data-toggle=".company-brands"><h4>Finance</h4></a>
</div>

<div class="company-brands" id="technology">
 <h1>Technology</h1>
</div>
<div class="company-brands" id="retail" hidden>
  <h1>retail</h1>
</div>
<div class="company-brands" id="finance" hidden>
  <h1>finance</h1>
</div>
```